# Term for "Group wants to do it, lets do it, but in reality no one wants to do it"

Tags: terminology

Term for the situation where "No individual in the group wants to do an activity, but they all agree to do it anyway because everyone thinks everyone else likes it"

Comment: You're speaking of the Republican presidential debates?

Comment: I wish I were. I'm sure it would seem appropriate :D
Anyway I found the answer from Chris's answer. It is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abilene_paradox

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of [groupthink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupthink), although that term is more general than this specfic situation.

> Groupthink is a psychological phenomenon that occurs within a group of people, in which the desire for harmony or conformity in the group results in an irrational or dysfunctional decision-making outcome.

Comment: Thank you very much Chris! Your sugestion "Groupthink" led me to the exact term I have been hunting for over the last two days. It is called Abilene Paradox. Thanks again man!

Comment: +1 because apparently the OP thought so well of this answer he didn't even give it an upvote.

Comment: Robusto and Chris, I did try to upvote it. But I didn't have enough reputations. :(

Edit: Now I do, and have upvoted :) thanks much guys!

Answer (score 1):

Chris's answer "Groupthink", led me to the exact term I was looking for. It is called '[Abilene Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abilene_paradox)'. Thanks again everyone!